# Using STAN (related to BUGS/JAGS) to do linear regression with with ARMA(1,1) noise?

Tags: regression, markov-chain-montecarlo, stan

EDIT: I've modified my STAN code and it looks like I am getting numbers close to using R's `arima`. The original code, now moved to the end, was incorrect.

I've been using STAN for simple things, but want to do a linear regression that has ARMA(1,1) noise. I've heard that this is basically equivalent to AR(1) + White Noise. I've made an attempt that gives reasonable numbers but I can't tell if I'm actually doing what I think I'm doing.

The reason I'm attempting to do this is that the data is a climate temperature time series, which is thus serially correlated, and so I believe OLS regression  -- used to calculate a trend -- will underestimate the uncertainty in the regression, which is reflected in the SE's of the slope and intercept coefficients. (And also in the residual error?)

My code, using `rstan`:

```
temps <-
    structure(c(-0.59, -0.17, 0.05, -0.7, -0.27, -0.94, -0.69, -0.96, 
    -0.58, -0.35, -0.58, -0.54, -0.48, -1.41, -0.82, -0.73, -0.48, 
    -0.37, -0.07, -0.16, -0.58, -0.43, -0.16, -0.19, -0.81, -0.37, 
    -0.52, -0.55, -0.51, -0.85, -0.43, -0.72, -0.43, -0.63, 0.16, 
    -0.26, -0.14, -0.48, -0.61, -0.36, -0.05, 0.22, -0.34, -0.23, 
    -0.2, -0.18, 0.51, -0.2, 0.28, -0.53, -0.07, 0.09, 0.45, -0.27, 
    -0.12, -0.35, -0.21, 0.11, 0.37, 0.09, -0.18, 0.14, 0.35, -0.16, 
    0.62, 0.04, 0.32, -0.12, 0.41, 0.28, -0.4, -0.34, 0.2, 0.26, 
    -0.27, 0.44, -0.11, -0.15, 0.68, 0.24, 0.12, 0.16, 0.33, 0.12, 
    -0.04, -0.01, -0.22, -0.14, -0.26, -0.42, -0.01, -0.1, -0.57, 
    0.16, -0.31, 0.12, 0.06, -0.19, 0.1, -0.01, 0.16, 0.81, -0.13, 
    0.53, 0.31, 0.06, 0.34, 0.23, 0.57, 0.07, 0.41, 0.51, 0.52, 0.39, 
    0.34, 0.73, 0.3, 0.38, 0.66, 0.6, 0.35, 0.55, 0.98, 0.89, 0.67, 
    0.86, 0.6, 1.31, 0.2, 0.75, 0.72, 0.53, 0.48), .Tsp = c(1880, 
    2012, 1), class = "ts")

stan.code1 <-
"data
    {
    int<lower=1> N ;
    real x[N] ;
    real y[N] ;
    }

parameters
    {
    real alpha ;
    real beta ;
    real kappa ;

    real<lower=0> sigma0 ;
    }

model
    {
    real sigma[N] ;

    alpha ~ cauchy (0, 5) ;
    beta  ~ cauchy (0, 5) ;

    kappa ~ gamma (1.2, 1) ;
    sigma0 ~ gamma (3, 1) ;
    sigma[1] <- sigma0 ;

    y[1] ~ normal (alpha + beta * x[1], sigma[1]) ;

    for (n in 2:N)
        {
        sigma[n] <- sigma0 + kappa * sigma[n-1] ;

        y[n] ~ normal (alpha + beta * x[n], sigma[n]) ;
        }
    }"

    stan.list1 <- list (N=length (temps), x=1880:2012, y=temps)

    stan.model1 <- stan (model_code=stan.code1, model_name="GISS NH Jan", data=stan.list1, iter=15000, chain=4)

    print (stan.model1, digits_summary=8)
```

The alpha, beta, and sigma appear to be reasonable if I use them to throw lines onto the data using `abline`.

QUESTIONS:

1. Have I really done a linear regression with AR(1) noise plus white noise? That is ARMA(1,1) noise? I believe $\kappa={{1-\theta}\over{1-\phi}}$.
2. Given that it is done properly -- either I lucked out, or someone will post a correct version of the STAN code -- how would I use kappa in calculating the larger uncertainty interval around the regression?

EDIT: Original code I used, with `rstan`:

```
temps <-
structure(c(-0.59, -0.17, 0.05, -0.7, -0.27, -0.94, -0.69, -0.96, 
-0.58, -0.35, -0.58, -0.54, -0.48, -1.41, -0.82, -0.73, -0.48, 
-0.37, -0.07, -0.16, -0.58, -0.43, -0.16, -0.19, -0.81, -0.37, 
-0.52, -0.55, -0.51, -0.85, -0.43, -0.72, -0.43, -0.63, 0.16, 
-0.26, -0.14, -0.48, -0.61, -0.36, -0.05, 0.22, -0.34, -0.23, 
-0.2, -0.18, 0.51, -0.2, 0.28, -0.53, -0.07, 0.09, 0.45, -0.27, 
-0.12, -0.35, -0.21, 0.11, 0.37, 0.09, -0.18, 0.14, 0.35, -0.16, 
0.62, 0.04, 0.32, -0.12, 0.41, 0.28, -0.4, -0.34, 0.2, 0.26, 
-0.27, 0.44, -0.11, -0.15, 0.68, 0.24, 0.12, 0.16, 0.33, 0.12, 
-0.04, -0.01, -0.22, -0.14, -0.26, -0.42, -0.01, -0.1, -0.57, 
0.16, -0.31, 0.12, 0.06, -0.19, 0.1, -0.01, 0.16, 0.81, -0.13, 
0.53, 0.31, 0.06, 0.34, 0.23, 0.57, 0.07, 0.41, 0.51, 0.52, 0.39, 
0.34, 0.73, 0.3, 0.38, 0.66, 0.6, 0.35, 0.55, 0.98, 0.89, 0.67, 
0.86, 0.6, 1.31, 0.2, 0.75, 0.72, 0.53, 0.48), .Tsp = c(1880, 
2012, 1), class = "ts")

stan.code1 <-
"data
    {
    int<lower=1> N ;
    real x[N] ;
    real y[N] ;
    }

parameters
    {
    real alpha ;
    real beta ;
    real kappa ;

    real<lower=0> sigma ;
    }

model
    {
    alpha ~ cauchy (0, 5) ;
    beta  ~ cauchy (0, 5) ;
    kappa ~ cauchy (0, 5) ;
    sigma ~ gamma (3, 1) ;

    y[1] ~ normal (alpha + beta * x[1], sigma) ;

    for (n in 2:N)
        {
        y[n] ~ normal (alpha + beta * x[n] + kappa * y[n-1], sigma) ;
        }
    }"

stan.list1 <- list (N=length (temps), x=1880:2012, y=temps)

stan.model1 <- stan (model_code=stan.code1, model_name="GISS NH Jan", data=stan.list1, iter=15000, chain=4)

print (stan.model1, digits_summary=8)
```

Comment: The Stan manual now has an ARMA model. https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/autoregressive-moving-average-models.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a first order autoregressive model and the noise is just normal, you aren't doing anything to it. What you should use depends on wether the autocorrelation is induced by dynamic misspecification (which your current formulation takes care of if the mean is in fact an ar1 process) or whether the dgp induces autocorrelated errors on top of mean autoregression. Autocorrelated errors could also be due to omitted variables or another form of misspecification.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Unfortunately, I think what I'm trying to do is mentioned in the sentence, "Of course, models could be defined where both the mean and scale vary over time; the econometrics literature presents a wide range of time-series modeling choices." I guess my difficulty is that to accomplish what I want, sigma at time t shouldn't depend on y[t-1] but rather on sigma at time t-1, right? So do I make sigma a vector, perhaps something like "normal (..., sigma0 + sigma[n-1])"?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is referred to as a stochastic volatility model. I am not terribly familiar with them though. I added some more explanation to my answer.

Comment: Very good. I've edited my question to see if it helps clarify which of the options you offer might be the right one for my problem. (I like the distinction and think it makes your answer better to include all of them, but obviously am most concerned with my particular problem.)